# Maven - unable to download dependencies behind Proxy Error Code - 307 Temporary Redirect

Tags: maven, redirect

I am using Maven to run a Java project. My issue is that I am not able to download the dependencies. It is giving the following error

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.7.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.7.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.7.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.7.1.pom. Error code 307, Temporary Redirect -> [Help 1]

The settings.xml is properly configured with the proxy details (since I am behind a proxy)  Still, I am not able to access the maven repo to download.

**UPDATE:** Thanks a lot landal79.I revisited this issue after some time. Still this issue gives me a nightmare.
Currently, I am not able to create any Maven Project. I am 100% sure this is due to a proxy issue. But not able to 
nail it down to where  exactly the issue.

When I try creating a project selecting an archetype, I am not able to create a maven project. I am getting the below error

"Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.

Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\rrr.m2\repository)

Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\rrr.m2\repository)"

I try creating this project through Eclipse. The settings.xml point to the right proxy ( cross checked with the Network connections dialog (window ->General->NetworkConenction Dialog). But the issue still persists.

So what I did was installed standalone Maven and create a maven project from command prompt. To my surprise,I am not able to download the archetypes in Maven Repo though other plugins are getting downloaded (Surefire plugin and JUNit jar for example)

Is there any work around to resolve the archetype download issue?

I tried your solution, but the issue still persists. When I create a simple maven project (without using any archetypes) I am getting "Unable to build Project " Error

PS: The proxy settings are defined in settings.xml and they are correct. Also, the eclipse proxy settings are correct (Since I am able to install plugins from Eclipse MarketPlace)

Eclipse experts - please help me resolve this issue. Thanks a lot in advance for help.

Thanks

Comment: Does your proxy require authentication?

Comment: Yes. I supplied the authentication details in the network settings in Eclipse. Still not able to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: I experienced some problem with windows with active directory authentication, I solved using [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I downloaded Cntlm and followed the steps. But still the issue persists. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was facing a lot of issues with various versions of Maven. At last lady luck smiled on me. I used Maven 3.0.3 which resolved all these issues. This might help the Maven community. Still wondering if any one faced this issue behind a corporate firewall and able to solve  the issue I faced. Thanks.